# How can I make a self-generating button?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, button

I'm attempting to create a function that will create a button named after a variable every time the submit to database function is used (1 button for every dataset submitted to my database). Currently I can get the button to name itself, but I'm having trouble offsetting the line for each time it's used. I could just add a simple counter and set row=n, but at this point I'm not sure my approach to the problem is the best. For every dataset there needs to be a button generated for it. Would it be best to approach this by trying to run a program that makes buttons based on my dataset (not exactly sure how I'd do this) or by having my submit return a button with row=counter? Or is there another solution I haven't thought of?

**Note: Looking back on this my buttons don't stay after the program restarts which makes sense. If I'm going to use the submit/counter solution I'll also have to make the data store itself in the code.

**Minimal reproducible code:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Button')
root.geometry('400x400')
f_name = Entry(root, width=30)
f_name.grid(row=0, column=1)
f_name_lbl = Label(root, text="First Name:")
f_name_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

def gen_button():
    auto_button = Button(root, text=f_name.get())
    auto_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

submit_btn = Button(root, text="Submit:", command=gen_button).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=100)
```

I believe I did that right, I apologize I'm new to python and stack overflow

Comment: This question is too vague. Please try to create a [mcve] that doesn't require an external database.

Comment: @BryanOakley I updated it with a minimal example, I apologize.

Comment: You can use `.grid_size()` to get the number of columns and rows used in the grid layout.  So just like `Button(...).grid(row=root.grid_size()[1], ...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 So this will be an active database, records will be added and updated frequently. From my understanding of your solution and the grid_size function, that won't offset the row every time nor would it store the button inside the program. Along with getting these buttons to offset, I can't get them to stay after I close out the program

Comment: how to get the buttons to appear, and how to get them to persist once destroying and restarting the GUI, are two separate problems and need to be asked about in two separate questions.

Comment: @EvlSmasher Your question is how to offset the newly created button inside `gen_button()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify a row, `grid` will automatically pick the next row after the last occupied row.

```
auto_button.grid(column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Though, if you create a separate frame for these buttons you can use `pack` which is a bit easier since `pack` aligns widgets along a side. In your case you want them aligned to the top of the frame, just below any other widgets.

```
def gen_button():
    auto_button = Button(button_frame, text=f_name.get())
    auto_button.pack(side="top")

submit_btn = Button(root, text="Submit:", command=gen_button)
submit_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=100)

button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: I just read your comment. I'll start a new thread for it. Thanks